# Не получается сделать udp сервер на Android

Tags: android, сервер, android-studio, сокет, udp

Скажите пожалуйста, почему у меня "вылетает" приложение когда я пытаюсь открыть socket на прослушивание? Заранее говорю, что в манифесте `android.permission.INTERNET` есть.

**Вот ошибка** :

> 05-02 00:48:30.235 15305-15305/hello.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                         Process: myhome.myapplication, PID: 15305
>                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick
>                                                                             at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)
>                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                             at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
>                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
>                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                          Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                             at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
>                                                                             at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:249)
>                                                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:549)
>                                                                             at
>   java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.doRecv(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:163)
>                                                                             at
>   java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:171)
>                                                                             at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:274)
>                                                                             at
>   myhome.myapplication.MainActivity.runUdpServer(MainActivity.java:84)
>                                                                             at
>   myhome.myapplication.MainActivity.butHello_Click(MainActivity.java:29)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447) 
>                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
>                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

**Вот код** :

```
private void runUdpServer() {

    String lText;

    byte[] lMsg = new byte[MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN];

    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(lMsg, lMsg.length);

    DatagramSocket ds = null;

    try {

        ds = new DatagramSocket(UDP_SERVER_PORT);

        //disable timeout for testing

        //ds.setSoTimeout(100000);

        ds.receive(dp);

        lText = new String(lMsg, 0, dp.getLength());

        Log.i("UDP packet received", lText);

        textView.setText(lText);

    } catch (SocketException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        if (ds != null) {

            ds.close();

        }

    }

}
```

---

**UPD** :

Ну вот, я переделал, но серв так запускаться и не хочет. Если что, то я с виртуальной машины (Android Jelly Bean) пытаюсь подсоединиться к своему телефону (Android 6.0.1) который в сети wifi весит под ip 192.168.1.35.

**Ошибка** :

> 05-02 13:14:10.570 8844-8844/myhome.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                       Process: myhome.myapplication, PID: 8844
>                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick
>                                                                           at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                           at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
>                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                        Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                           at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
>                                                                           at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:249)
>                                                                           at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:549)
>                                                                           at
>   java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.doRecv(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:163)
>                                                                           at
>   java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:171)
>                                                                           at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:274)
>                                                                           at
>   myhome.myapplication.MainActivity$UdpServer.run(MainActivity.java:104)
>                                                                           at
>   myhome.myapplication.MainActivity$UdpServer.(MainActivity.java:87)
>                                                                           at myhome.myapplication.MainActivity.btnserver(MainActivity.java:40)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                           at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447) 
>                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
>                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

**Код** :

```
public void btnclient(View v) {
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Thread t = new Thread(new UdpClient());
    t.start();
}

public void btnserver(View v) {
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Thread t = new Thread(new UdpServer());
    t.start();
}

public TextView textView;
public EditText edittext;

private static final int UDP_SERVER_PORT = 17171;
private static final int MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN = 1500;

class UdpClient implements Runnable {


    UdpClient() {
        run();
    }

    public void run() {
        String udpMsg = "hello world from UDP client " + UDP_SERVER_PORT;
        DatagramSocket ds = null;
        try {
            ds = new DatagramSocket();
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(edittext.getText().toString());
            DatagramPacket dp;
            dp = new DatagramPacket(udpMsg.getBytes(), udpMsg.length(), serverAddr, UDP_SERVER_PORT);
            ds.send(dp);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (ds != null) {
                ds.close();
            }
        }
    }
}


class UdpServer implements Runnable {

    UdpServer() {
        run();
    }

    public void run() {

        String lText;

        byte[] lMsg = new byte[MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN];

        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(lMsg, lMsg.length);

        DatagramSocket ds = null;

        try {

            ds = new DatagramSocket(UDP_SERVER_PORT);

            ds.receive(dp);

            lText = new String(lMsg, 0, dp.getLength());

            Log.i("UDP packet received", lText);

            //System.out.println(lText);

        } catch (SocketException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            if (ds != null) {

                ds.close();

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ключевой кусок лога:

> Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273) at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:249) at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:549) at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.doRecv(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:163) at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:171) at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:274) at myhome.myapplication.MainActivity.runUdpServer(MainActivity.java:84) at

Нельзя сетевую активность инициировать из главного потока приложения.
Запускайте свой метод из отдельного потока.

Comment: Неа, не помогает, тему обновил.

Comment: Кто же так делает :) Кто ж в конструкторе `Runnable` сразу `run()` вызывает? У вас в результате те же грабли, вид сбоку.

Comment: ну как же правильно тогда сделать? Я уже попробовал сначала запустить просто поток и потом отдельно run, но не помогает :(((

Comment: Да просто удалите конструкторы у `UdpServer` и `UdpClient`, все сразу заработает.

Comment: Если я убираю конструкторы и оставляю только `new UdpServer();`, то `run()` не запускается.

Comment: Так самое что интересное, если сделать `new Thread(new UdpServer()).start();`, то заход в `run()` происходит, но вылетает на строчке с `receive`

Comment: Вылет на `receive` будет по абсолютно другой причине, создайте новый вопрос.